# how to find file system utilization in Linux and if its exceeding a certain limit then some action?

Tags: linux, bash, aix

how to calculate file system utilization system i.e. free and used space in all drives. If any drive is exceeding a threshold limit it should print top 10 files or directory as per space usage. The limit can be like %used memory.

please help me to write a bash script for Linux/AIX.

Comment: What have you written, or tried, so far?

Comment: I just found the file system usage by this command "df -k|sed 's/  */\t/g;s/%//'|cut -f 5" but output showing one line of drive path so I was not able to go ahead.

Comment: Not sure why you get a single line from that command. I get one letter per line, the 4th letter of each original line actually. Assuming a typo, I tried `df -k|sed 's/ +/\t/g;s/%//'|cut -f 5`, changing the `*` to `+`, and got a formatted series of lines that looks just like the original. What were you expecting from that command?

Comment: i was expecting just the usage % of disk in numeric value for comparing them to my threshold value.

Comment: Then let `df` do the work for you. To get just the percents us `df --output=pcent`. To strip the "%" sign off, as you already know, use `df --output=pcent|sed 's/%//g'`. Though that's not going to help much without knowing the disk it's on, so add that to the list this way `df --output=pcent,target|sed 's/%//g'`. Moving from here you should be able to process the data however you intended to. The `man1 df` page will give you the other options for that command if you need them.

Comment: above command is not working as I tried on linux

Comment: Too late to edit it, but I think I know which "above command" you mean. There should be a space between `man` and `1`. My typo. The other 3 work in `bash` and should work in other shells as well, since I don't believe they do anything non-standard.

Comment: not this one but the df command

Comment: I don't know how AIX is different than standard Linux, so the last command is your best choice. Then `man` pages for your system should show you how to use the commands it has.

Comment: I found the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds.navigation/alphabeticallistofcommands.htm) for AIX 7.2 commands and to fix that command it need to be close to this: `df -F %z` which should list the file system the blocks allocated and the percent used. You can pass it through `sed` to modify it as needed. Try `df -F %z | sed gs/%//g' | awk '{ print $1" "$3}'` to get something like `/dev/sda1 87` for 87% used on `sda1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds.navigation/alphabeticallistofcommands.htm) for differences in the commands needed, I think I've got it worked out. **Be advised**, there is no way for me to test this in AIX, so it's based on what I can learn of AIX's differences from the above site. In standard GNU/Linux tools, prior to coversion of some of the options, it tests as good. YMMV.

To start with, we can get the list of file systems, and what percentage is used on each, along with the file system size (which we can't turn off), and the mount point, which we may need for later processing. Using `df -F %z %m` returns something like `/dev/sda1 1545476 78% /home`, meaning 78 percent of the 1545476 blocks on device `/dev/sda1`, mounted on `/home` are in use.

Since we only need to know the file system and mount point, to check it out further, and the percent used, without the "%" sign, we modify the output using `sed` and `awk`. While doing that, we might as well put the uasge first and the name second, strip out the lines that don't represent real file systems, and get the mount point for each file system. This'll make it easier to process later. Lastly we can sort it in descending percentage used so that the most important ones are first. This gives us the command:

```
df -F %z %m | grep -e '^/dev/[sh]d' | sed 's/%//g' | awk '{print $3" "$1" \""$4"\""}' | sort -rn
```

Final output for a line is like this `78 /dev/sda1 /home`.

Now we can use this as the input to a loop that reads each line and processes it as we want, based on a preset `action_limit`, here set at 75. Save it as a shell script, with execute permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash
action_limit=75;
df -F %z %m \
    | grep -e '^/dev/[sh]d' \
    | sed 's/%//g' \
    | awk '{print $3" "$1" "$4}' \
    | sort -r -n \
    | while read -r pct dsk mnt; do
        if test $action_limit -le $pct; then
            echo "$mnt for $dsk is using ${pct}%";
        fi;
    done
```

The line with `echo` needs to be replaced with the command of what you want to do with those file systems, now that you know which ones qualify. The `echo` command shows where the other command needs to be called, and shows what information is available to pass to that script. Not everything needs to be used. Most likely only the mount point, `$mnt`, will be needed. Be advised that `$mnt` contains a directory path, which may contain spaces or other dangerous shell characters, and should be enclosed in quotes when used as a parameter to another script or command.

To merely list the top files/directories by size on the quaifying file systems, we don't need to create a whole new script to call. We can simply add one command to the above, giving the modified shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
action_limit=75;
top_count=10;
df -F %z %m \
    | grep -e '^/dev/[sh]d' \
    | sed 's/%//g' \
    | awk '{print $3" "$1" "$4}' \
    | sort -r -n \
    | while read -r pct dsk mnt; do
        if test $action_limit -le $pct; then
            echo "$mnt for $dsk is using $pct%";
            du -s -x -m "$mnt"/* | sort -rn | head -$top_count| awk '{SZ=$1;$1="";print "\t"SZ"\t"$0}';
        fi;
    done
```

The output will be, in descending order, the file systems that meet or exceed the set limit, `action_limit`, followed by the files or directories using the most space on that filesystem. How many files or directories are listed is set by the new variable `top_count`. These are indented under their mount points to keep things neat and readable, and include the total size of each file or directory in megabytes. (The `-m` controlls that, and can be changed to `-k` for kilobytes, or `-g` for gigabytes. Megabytes seemed like a good compromise.)

Lastly, you used the `/bash` tag, so all testing was done in `bash`, and if there are any bash-specific tests or syntax used, I didn't catch them. Therefore, if you have some other shell, test it carefully before trusting it.